# How to mask some position of string in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some date as below.
I want to mask these values.

```
const name = "Smith"
const name2 = "Kithmatch"
const number = "342782828"
const number2 = "012221112230"
```

After masking,

```
const name = "S***h"
const name2 = "K*******h"
const number = "342**2828"
const number2 = "012*****2230"
```

There are two conditions between name and number.
In name only first and last string survive. And in number three number from front and four number from end survive.
How can I make this masking in javascript? Thank you so much for reading it.

Comment: number's condition need more specification

Comment: @Captain Mhmdrz_A In number only three number from front and four number from end survives.

Comment: there is regex pattern for that; currently im on mobile btw;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply take the start and the end and insert the `*` with the `repeat` function. The `start` and `end` variables can simply be adjusted. String `slice` gets a part of a string which we will take to insert with `+=`

Note that if there are too less characters, no `*` will be inserted.

```js
var s = "342782828";
var start = 1;
var end = 1;

if (!isNaN(s)) { // check if is number
 start = 3;
 end = 4;
}

result = s.slice(0, start);
result += "*".repeat(s.length-start-end);
result += s.slice(s.length-end);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this can be achieved with regex.
For a JS solution you can look at the snippet below.

It uses the substring, slice and repeat methods of String.

The substring() method returns the part of the string between the start and end indexes, or to the end of the string.

The slice() method extracts a section of a string and returns it as a new string, without modifying the original string.

The repeat() method constructs and returns a new string which contains the specified number of copies of the string on which it was called, concatenated together.

Learn more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods

```js
const name = "Smith"
const name2 = "Kithmatch"
const number = "342782828"
const number2 = "012221112230"



const maskName = (name) => {
  const mask = "*";
  let maskedName = name.substring(0,1) + mask.repeat(name.length-2) + name.slice(-1);
  return maskedName;
};

const maskNumber = (number) => {
  const mask = "*";
  let maskedNumber = number.substring(0, 3) + mask.repeat(number.length-7) + number.slice(-4);
  return maskedNumber;
};

console.log(maskName(name));
console.log(maskName(name2));
console.log(maskNumber(number));
console.log(maskNumber(number2));
```

Comment: this snippet does no type or length checking.